# How do I prevent images in imageview from being cropped to a square?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I am trying to create a splash screen for my app, but the image keeps getting cropped to a square in the center of the screen.  The mockup of the screen in the "Graphical Layout" tab in Eclipse looks good, but when I test it on the emulator or my phone, the image is clipped/cropped to a square in the center of the screen.

Screenshot from emulator is available [here](http://i1191.photobucket.com/albums/z473/miekagoff/screenshot.jpg).

The code for this is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/digitalorange" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which Android version & API level are you developing?

Comment: Is that all code you have in your activity xml? Have you tried putting the ImageView into RelativeLayout or FrameLayout just to narrow down problem space?

Comment: I have tried relative and frame, but that didn't help.  I'm working in 2.3.3 (level 10, I think).  That is all the code in the splashscreen.xml.

Comment: Try clean + refresh + build project. If that doesn't work then try using either fill_parent or match_parent. They're the same thing but you never know... If that doesn't work then show us your manifest, the whole image as you have it, and the activity code.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to your `ImageView` and see if it gives what you want.

Comment: That doesn't help.  I still get the same result in the emulator.  In the "Graphical Layout" tab it distorts the image, since it isn't being stretched proportionately.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` to your ImageView